# typescript + redux: exclude redux props in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am using redux and typescript for my current webapp.

What is the best practice to define the props of a component which receives redux-actions via `@connect`, but also props from parent?
Example:

```
// mychild.tsx
export namespace MyChildComponent {

  export interface IProps {
    propertyFromParent: string;
    propertyFromRedux: string;  // !!!! -> This is the problem
    actionsPropertyFromRedux: typeof MyReduxActions;  // !!!! -> And this     
  }
}

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export class MyChildComponent extends React.Component <MyChildComponent.IProps, any> {

... react stuff

}

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    propertyFromRedux: state.propertyFromRedux
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actionsPropertyFromRedux: bindActionCreators(MyReduxActions as any, dispatch)
  };
}




// myparent.tsx
export class MyParentComponent extends React.Component <MyParentComponent.IProps, any> {

... react stuff

    render(){
        // typescript complains, because I am not passing `propertyFromRedux`! 
        return <div><MyChildComponent propertyFromParent="yay" /></div>;
    }

}
```

As I see it I got 2 solutions.

1. Just pass the actions & state down through my whole app. But that would mean that my whole app gets re-rendered even when just some small child component would have to change. Or is it the redux way to listen in my top level component on all store changes? Then I would have to write a lot of logic inside `shouldComponentUpdate` for props which are no flat objects.
2. Set the param in `IProps` of `MyChildComponent`  optional like this:

-

```
// mychild.tsx
export namespace MyChildComponent {

  export interface IProps {
    propertyFromParent: string;
    propertyFromRedux?: typeof MyAction;  // This is the problem
  }
}
```

Is there another way? Both of the above ways seem too messy in my eyes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to split up your props - you'll need a `DispatchProps`, `StateProps`, and an `OwnProps` type. You'll also have to use TypeScript's generics with `connect`

- `DispatchProps` are your action creators.
- `StateProps` are your state props (duh) - these come from `mapStateToProps` - the return type of that function should match this type.
- `OwnProps` are props which are accepted (and perhaps expected) by your component. Optional props should be marked as optional in the interface.

The way I do it (without decorators, but i'm sure it applies here) is

```
interface ComponentDispatchProps {
    doSomeAction: typeof someAction;
}

interface ComponentStateProps {
    somethingFromState: any;
}

interface ComponentOwnProps {
    somethingWhichIsRequiredInProps: any;
    somethingWhichIsNotRequiredInProps?: any;
}

// not necessary to combine them into another type, but it cleans up the next line
type ComponentProps = ComponentStateProps & ComponentDispatchProps & ComponentOwnProps;

class Component extends React.Component<ComponentProps, {}> {...}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) { 
    return { somethingFromState };
}

export default connect<ComponentStateProps, ComponentDispatchProps, ComponentOwnProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Component);
```

I think you have to use `@connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>` which will decorate and return a class which accepts `OwnProps`.

If you look at `connect`s implementation in TS

```
export declare function connect<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>(...): ComponentDecorator<TStateProps & TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>

interface ComponentDecorator<TOriginalProps, TOwnProps> {
    (component: ComponentClass<TOriginalProps> | StatelessComponent<TOriginalProps>): ComponentClass<TOwnProps>;
}
```

`connect<...>` returns a `ComponentDecorator`, which, when passed the component (in your case this is done transparently when transpiling the decorator out), regardless of `StateProps`, and `DispatchProps` returns a component which expects `OwnProps`.

`connect` (non-generic) returns `InferableComponentDecorator`

```
export interface InferableComponentDecorator {
    <P, TComponentConstruct extends (ComponentClass<P> | StatelessComponent<P>)>(component: TComponentConstruct): TComponentConstruct;
}
```

which attempts to infer the props based on the props supplied to the component, which in your case is the combination of all props (`OwnProps` becomes `ComponentProps` from above).

Comment: Thanks alot! That did the trick. It is not working with the `@connect` decorator and I also had to remove the `namespace`, but when I use the regular `export default connect(...)` like in your example it works. When I use the decorator I get a compiler error `Type 'Component<IOwnProps, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'WbUserEditComponent'.
      Property 'componentDidMount' is missing in type 'Component<IOwnProps, ComponentState>`. I think this is a typing issue with the decorator.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help out using decorators - I tried in the past to use decorators and couldn't get them working, a well. Glad I could at least sort of resolve your issue, though.

Comment: If you make the types of the arguments in mapStateToProps and/or mapDispatchToProps explicit, then TypeScript should be able to infer the generic type parameters in `connect`.  I think the first argument for each can be `any`, and the second argument would have the type `ComponentOwnProps`

Comment: @mikebridge yeah `state` is actually the combined schema of all reducers, but `any` works, too (though you lose some nice intellisense). The second argument is `ComponentOwnProps`, yes.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Sorry, yes, I just meant that adding the second type would allow him to drop the explicit generic type parameters to `connect` without losing anything, i.e. it would become: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);`

Comment: Not sure why this solution isn't successful for me -- what typing versions and react-redux versions were this with?

Comment: You'll want to include your root reducer state type as a fourth param for connect(). I found this thread helpful for debugging: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16990#issuecomment-507509882

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can setup types manually. But much comfortable to use generated, that you actually get from `connect`. It helps to avoid annoying duplicates.

**Example 1:**

```
type Props = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> & ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: ReduxState) => ({
  me: state.me,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ReduxDispatch) => ({
  doSomething: () => dispatch(Dispatcher.doSomething()),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Now we get types directly from redux state and action/dispatch functions.

After some time we simplified this example to:

**Example 2:**

```
//// other file
import { InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps } from 'react-redux'

type ExtractConnectType<T> = T extends InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<infer K, any> ? K : T
//// <= Save it somewhere and import

type Props = ExtractConnectType<typeof connectStore>

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  ...
}

const connectStore = connect(
  (state: ReduxState) => ({
    me: state.me,
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    doSomething: () => dispatch(Dispatcher.doSomething()),
  })
)

export default connectStore(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply,
a component should be clear on what `props` should be coming from a parent and `connect` (redux).

Now, `connect()` can issue `redux state` (your app state) or `action` as a `prop` to the component and the rest `props` of the component should be coming from the parent.

As suggested, it is better to break the component props into 3 parts (`ComponentStateProps`, `ComponentDispatchProps` `&` `ComponentOwnProps`) and then use them in `connect()`.  And, join these 3 props to form `ComponentProps`.

I think the below code will give a better understanding.

```
// Your redux State    
type SampleAppState = {
   someState: any;
};

// State props received from redux
type ChildStateProps = {
  propFromState: any;
};

// dispatch action received from redux (connect)
type ChildDispatchProps = {
  actionAsProp: () => void;
};

// Props received from parent
type ChildOwnProps = {
  propFromParent: any;
};

// All Props
type ChildProps = ChildStateProps & ChildDispatchProps & ChildOwnProps;

const ChildComponent = (props: ChildProps) => {
  return <>{/*....*/}</>;
};

let ConnectedChildComponent = connect<
  ChildStateProps,
  ChildDispatchProps,
  ChildOwnProps,
  SampleAppState
>(
  (appState: SampleAppState, ownProps: ChildOwnProps) => {
    // Shape that matches ChildStateProps
    return {
      propFromState: appState.someState,
    };
  },
  (dispatch, ownProps: ChildOwnProps) => {
    return bindActionCreators(
      // Shape that matches ChildDispatchProps
      {
        actionAsProp: () => {},
      },
      dispatch,
    );
  },
)(ChildComponent);

const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ConnectedChildComponent propFromParent={'Prop Value'} />
    </>
  );
};
```