# Pass store to the layout component in react router redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

I want to pass props and invoke actions in my Layout component. When I try to do it with the following code, only the initial state is passed. The changes in the redux store are not reflected.

This is the code to initiate the app.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <ConnectedRouter history={ history } >
                <Layout prop={store.getState()}>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={ Dashboard } />
                    <Route path='/workorder' component={ WorkOrder } />
                    <Route path='/programs' component={ Programs } />
                    <Route path='/departments' component={ Departments } />
                    <Route path='/users' component={ Users } />
                    <Route path='/fetchdata/:startDateIndex?' component={ FetchData } />
                </Layout>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

This is the code of the layout page.

```
interface LayoutProps{
    prop: any;
}

export class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps, {}> {
    public render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return <div>  
                    <Header/>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <NavMenu/>
                        { this.props.children }
                    </div>
               </div>;
    }
}
```

My console log only prints the initial state all the time. I don't know why it is not getting updated. I have this problem only for layout. All the other components defined in the routes are connected using 'connect' and works properly.

Edit: This is the updated code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
        <Provider store={ store }>
            <ConnectedRouter history={ history } >
                <Layout>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={ Dashboard } />
                    <Route path='/workorder' component={ WorkOrder } />
                    <Route path='/programs' component={ Programs } />
                    <Route path='/departments' component={ Departments } />
                    <Route path='/users' component={ Users } />
                    <Route path='/fetchdata/:startDateIndex?' component={ FetchData } />
                </Layout>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

This is the code in Layout:

```
export class Layout extends React.Component<any, {}> {

    public render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return <div>  
                    <Header/>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <NavMenu/>
                        { this.props.children }
                    </div>
               </div>;
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState) => state.users, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
    UsersStore.actionCreators.getCurrentUser              // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
)(Layout) as typeof Layout;
```

But only props.children are available inside the Layout component. All the other props are undefined even though I pass state.users, UsersStore.actionCreators.getCurrentUser. Basically it is not taking anything from redux store (Even after any number of re-renders).

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using `react-redux`'s `connect` enchancer.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { updateSomething } from 'actions'


class LayoutComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.updateSomething}>
       something: {this.props.something}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export Layout = connect((state) => { 
  return { something: state.something } 
}, { updateSomething })(LayoutComponent)
```

edit: see [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) for more information

Comment: Please see the updated question. I tried to connect the layout. But all the props are undefined except props.children which comes from the router i guess. I had a look at your answer here (didn't help). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502291/typescript-redux-exclude-redux-props-in-parent-component