# How to abstract Redux's connect method with Generics in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I would like to abstract Redux's `connect` method to make reusable and to avoid boilerplate code.

```
class Props {
    counterState?:CounterState;
}
class Counter extends React.Component<Props,{}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
export default connect<Props>((props:Props)=>props, {})(Counter);
```

The abstraction would need `<P>` for Props and `<C>` for the component. My problem is the following:

[image]

Any ideas how to pass the Counter component properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's between the `<...>`s are types - you're telling the compiler that you're going to use `P` and `C` (in this case) as types, but allow the caller to give you those types instead of defining them yourself.

You want something like

```
function wireUp<P>(C: React.ComponentClass<any>) {
  return connect<P>(props => props)(C);
}
```

where `P` is a generic type and `C` is a value (extending/implementing a Component)

iirc, though, connect takes three generic types. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43502291/typescript-redux-exclude-redux-props-in-parent-component/43502701#43502701).

Comment: dang it, I tried to pass it as argument, but somehow failed. Probably because I missed the `<any>` type. Thank you very much!